# PhpMyAdmin Error opening structure only using Italian language

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PhpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1 and, when I try to open "Structure" folder (and also when I click on "fields") I get the error (translated):

> Error processing the request
>   Error Code: 200
>   Error message: OK

I get the same error after an "ALTER TABLE" query (when PhpMyAdmin usually shows the structure).

But if i choose "open in another folder", by clicking right mouse button on the link, it works correctly.

If I change language to English the error disappear.

How can I fix?

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: You may also wish to track this bug report, though it seems intermittent and I haven't been able to reproduce it. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from LuigiMdg [in this issue on github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11705) (thanks to @IsaacBennetch for pointing it in comment)

> I solved temporally whit this sequence:
>   click on Struttura (structure), appear the message of error 200, click F5 (refresh) and the structure appear and work :)

Comment: Ok, waiting for bug removal it's an acceptable solution. ;)